# expected one of the following: CHECK CONSTRAINT DEFERRABLE EXCLUDE FOREIGN INITIALLY LIKE NOT PRIMARY UNIQUE identifier

Tags: sql, postgresql, intellij-idea

I create an SQL to a new table in Intellij IDE, and this one show me a warning:

> expected one of the following: CHECK CONSTRAINT DEFERRABLE EXCLUDE
>   FOREIGN INITIALLY LIKE NOT PRIMARY UNIQUE identifier

My script look like this:

```
create sequence sch_name.table_name_id_seq 
increment 1 start 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1;

create table sch_name.table_name (
    id bigint not null default nextval('sch_name.table_name_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(20),
    constraint table_name_pkey primary key (id)
);
```

The script work very fine, but the Intellij warning bothering me, Do I make any mistake? or it is just a non sens warning and should ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define the sequence?  This [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ab862419a678f6c8193fdddeac4259d5):

```
create sequence table_name_id_seq;

create table roles (
    id bigint not null default nextval('table_name_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(20),
    constraint table_name_pkey primary key (id)
);
```

I wouldn't recommend using sequences for this.  Postgres has better methods:

```
create table roles (
    id bigint not null generated always as identity,
    name character varying(20),
    constraint table_name_pkey primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: Ahah, tahnk you, it is interested way, does `generated always as identity` work as `auto_increment` in MySQL? There are also `Serial` which one you suggest to a better way?

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial